# Passing result variable to nested SELECT statement in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, nested

I have the following query which works:

```
SELECT
    SoftwareList,
    Count (SoftwareList) as Count
FROM [assigned]
GROUP BY SoftwareList
```

This returns the following result set:

```
*SoftwareList*  | *Count*
--------------------------
Office XP       | 3
Adobe Reader    | 3
Dreamewaver     | 2
```

I can also run the following query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(LastSeen) as LastSeen
FROM [assigned]
WHERE SoftwareList = 'Dreamweaver';
```

Which would return the following result set:

```
*LastSeen*
----------
2007-9-23,2012-3-12
```

I wish to combine both of these queries into one, so that the following results are returned:

```
*SoftwareList* | *Count* | *LastSeen*
--------------------------------------------------------
Office XP      | 3       | 2001-2-12,2008-3-19,2002-2-17
Adobe Reader   | 3       | 2008-2-12,2009-3-20,2007-3-16
Dreamewaver    | 2       | 2007-9-23,2012-3-12
```

I am trying this but don't know how to refer to the initial `SoftwareList` variable within the nested statement:

```
SELECT
    SoftwareList,
    Count (SoftwareList) as Count,
    (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(LastSeen) FROM [assigned]
        WHERE SoftwareList = SoftwareList
    ) as LastSeen
FROM [assigned]
GROUP BY SoftwareList;
```

How can I pass `SoftwareList` which is returned for each row, into the nested statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT SoftwareList, COUNT(SoftwareList) AS Count, GROUP_CONCAT(LastSeen) 
FROM assigned GROUP BY SoftwareList
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly.  Seems I was over complicating things in my head.